# React: choose from a select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do create a select, with 3 choices:

In the form page I have:

```
      <Form>
          <Form.Row>
            <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridState">
              <Form.Label>Choose One</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control as="select" defaultValue="" onChange={this.props.typology}>
                <option value="Starter">Starter</option>
                <option value="First">First</option>
                <option value="Second">Second</option>
              </Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>
          </Form.Row>
      </Form>
```

**1.** The first problem is right here, because it's directly choosen Starter, and I would like the box of choices to be empty and only by clicking will the 3 choices appear.

**2** My second problem is that the state doesn't take the value this.state.typology the first time, and if I choose another element from the list, the value this.state.typology becomes equal to the first value.

For example:

I choose Starter

```
this.state.typology:
```

Then I choose First,

```
this.state.typology: Starter
```

In the page where I call the form:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            typology: ""
        }
    }

typology(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      let choosen = event.target.value
      this.setState({typology: choosen})
    console.log("choosen: ", choosen)
    console.log("this.state.typology: ", this.state.typology)

//Now the first console.log (choosen) wrote the right value, the second console.log (typology) the first time is without value, if I choose another value from the list it becomes equal to the first value.
  }

render() {
    return (
      <Row>
        <Col className="text-recipts">
          <h5>Search One:</h5>
          <FormRecipts typology={this.typology.bind(this)}/>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    );
```

How can I solve? Thank you

Comment: the `setState` function is asynchronous, this function take as second arguement a callback function which will be execcuted just after the state is updated. So you should write `this.setState({typology: choosen}, () => console.log(this.state.typology))`

Comment: Ooh thank you, this is correct! :) Do you know about the first question? =)

Comment: You could add: `<option value="" disabled selected>Select an option</option>` just before the other options and it'll do the trick